# how to find out error Running command - failed! [ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.4.0

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

I'm create new application in ionic2 and platform ios but i hve add a platfrom ios command `ionic cordova platform add ios`  then error in `✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.4.0`

[image]

pls help me right suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the platform

try this

```
npm update -g
```

Readd the platform

Comment: @rangholiyanikunj Please mark it as the answer :) your welcome